# Using jsforce, after negotiating the OAUTH2 flow, obtaining refresh & access token, but can't use them

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, salesforce, jsforce

After placing the refresh token, access token and the instance URL in the session, I have the following code:

```
  app.get('/api/v1/refresh', function (req, res) {
    const conn = new jsforce.Connection({
      oauth2: {
        clientId: process.env.SALESFORCE_CONSUMER_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.SALESFORCE_CONSUMER_SECRET,
        redirectUri: process.env.SALESFORCE_CALLBACK_URL
      },
      instanceUrl: req.session.user.salesforce.instanceUrl,
      accessToken: req.session.user.salesforce.accessToken,
      refreshToken: req.session.user.salesforce.refreshToken
    })

    conn.oauth2.refreshToken(req.session.user.refreshToken, (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.json({ error: err.message })
      }
      res.json(results)
    })
  })
```

I'm aware you don't have to refresh with jsforce, but I'm just trying to see the tokens work. In this case, I get the error: `invalid_grant: expired access/refresh token` - but the token is only seconds old?

Using `conn.sobject`, `conn.query` or `conn.search` results in no callback being called.

The scopes setup for the OAUTH2 flow are:

- API
- profile
- web
- refresh_token, offline_access

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm seeing the same behavior where I get invalid_grant: expired access/refresh token, but my jsForce on('refresh', ...) is never being called with an updated access token

Answer (score 0):

The Salesforce documentation includes a note that the OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials Flow "doesn’t support refresh tokens".
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_client_credentials_flow.htm&type=5

In testing using Postman and the examples on the above page it looks like Salesforce doesn't include a refresh token when using grant_type = client_credentials.

I'm not confident this is directly related to the error you're facing with jsforce, but I had encountered this nuance before with Salesforce in general and thought it was worth being aware of.